# Oracle SQL How to extract a string on the first occurrence between two specific fixed strings of "//"

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

I have data in an Oracle column in the below format:

Ch99// 4// Sub// 586915 16// jkc 12/12/22

And I need to extract the substring of "4" that will always be between the first two occurrences of "//".

So the output needed is:

4

I'm currently using ,regexp_substr(column, '//([^}]+)//', 1,1,NULL,1) but it's returning everything after the first "//"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest thing is probably to use `'//(.*?)//'`. This matches any characters between `//` and `//`, but does it in a [non-greedy](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2786107/regular-expression-tutorial-part-5--greedy-and-non-greedy-quantification.html) way.

It is not clear why you are trying to use `[^}]+` (matches one or more characters that are not a closing curly brace), since your question doesn't mention any requirements around curly braces.

A [Fiddle of it working](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z28ADBhR) with your example:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(
 'Ch99// 4// Sub// 586915 16// jkc 12/12/22',
 '//(.*?)//', 
 1, 1, null, 1)
FROM dual
```

returns

```
4
```